# Does a user creating text file need to be in a specific place?

Tags: scripts, directory, users, nano, groups

I've got several scripts which wont work for me but work for others. Their purpose is to add users to the system, and then assign them to groups. I wrote it as a nano bash file; does it need to be saved in a specific place? I'm running the file in root at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute script with ./ if you are in same directory as script.  But if you want to run it from anywhere , you have to put the script into one of the folders listed in your $PATH preferably /usr/bin or add a custom folder to the list.

As for creating a file,  if you specify full path to script , like nano /usr/bin/myscript.sh , yoi don't have to be prese in that directory